# Computing Riemann-Liouville Integral using Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, calculus

New to calculus and not sure where this goes...

I'm trying to compute the Riemann-Liouville interpretation of the integral in Python using sympy. However the resulting integral when running my code between 0 and T contains T as a variable, which I do not want. What should I do to fix this?

Code:

```
def integral(f, order):
    gamma_recip = 1/gamma(order)
    T = sympy.Symbol('T')
    r = sympy.Symbol('r')
    eq = (T-r) ** order - 1
    function_eq = eq * f(r)
    integral = sympy.integrate(function_eq, (r, 0, T))
    return integral
```

Equation:

[image]

Sample call as requested:
`-0.333333333333333*T**3 + 0.0833333333333333*T**4.0`

Function and order used:

```
def f(x):
    return x**2
print(integral(f, 1.0))
```

Expected result:

`r**3/3`

Comment: Looks like the `mpmath` subpackage of SymPy can calculate the Riemann-Liouville integral with a function call, would this cover your use case? https://www.lidavidm.me/sympy/modules/mpmath/calculus/differentiation.html#fractional-derivatives-differintegration-differint

Comment: @Zsolt, I'd like my program to return a function not a float. The differint package comes close, but returns a set of points instead of a representation of the function.  https://pypi.org/project/differint/

Comment: Can you an example call to your function?  Is f a specific function, or a sympy variable? Is order a constant or a sympy variable?

Comment: The equation in your image uses `x` as parameter. So, if you would write `x` instead of `T`, the function would be more similar to your image. Also, you could give the `x` as an extra argument to `integral`.

Comment: @JohanC, I've updated the image to better reflect my code. Yes, f is a Python function, and order is a constant.

Comment: Please, please add a sample call, its result and the expected result. Preferably as code and text. Changing your uppercase `T` to a lower case `t` should give the same result as the image.

Comment: @JohanC, I updated with a call, the result of the call, and the expected result. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues:

1. you are using "T" as the integral limit so you will end up with that in the result; if you want "r" in the result, swap the use of T and r in your function
2. you didn't put parentheses around the `order - 1` in your definition of `eq`; if you do you will (with your current code) get the expected `T**3/3`